# Spring threadpooltaskexecutor: transaction managment

Tags: spring, transactions, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to make an asynchronous method call in my service layer code. Some pseudo code for the same is as below:

```
public void createXXX ()
{
  dao.saveOrUpdate(entity); // save an entity
  ...................
  ...................
  callAServiceXXX () 
}
...........
...........
public void callAServiceXXX()
{
   SomeEntity entity = dao.getEntity();  // entity NOT NULL
   this.threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                try {
                callAMethodXXX()
                }catch()
                {} 

}

public void callAMethodXXX()
{
   SomeEntity entity = dao.getEntity(); // entity always NULL
}
```

My spring config file has the following defined for the service layer bean containing the above logic:

```
 <property name="transactionAttributes">
               <props>
                    <prop key="callAServiceXXX">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                    <prop key="callAMethodXXX">PROPAGATION_MANDATORY</prop>
              </props>
          </property>
```

As put in the above, when I am trying to fetch the entity object which I save in the method createXXX(), it is always NULL when the dao call is executed from the callAMethodXXX() method.

I am not sure about the reason for this behavior. Did try a few other transactional attributes in the spring config file but did not get any success.

A workaround which I tried to make this work was:

1) Create a helper class. Inject it in this service layer class.
2) Shift the method callAMethodXXX() to this helper class.
3) Define `<prop key="callAMethodXXX">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW</prop>` as i want to make sure that callAMethodXXX() should be executed in a new transaction.

However, I do not want to use an extra helper class and want to make sure that the logic works fine from with the single service layer class.

Any inputs on the above will be helpful.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Your Runnable thread is not aware of transaction management.
Maybe you can try to add to your managed bean a reference to itself, and add TRANSACTION_REQUIRES_NEW for method callAMethod:

```
@Component
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    public MyService myService;

    public void callAServiceXXX() {
       SomeEntity entity = dao.getEntity();
       this.threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               try {
                   myService.callAMethodXXX();
               }catch(Exception e){
               }
           }
       });
    }
}

<property name="transactionAttributes">
    <props>
        <prop key="callAServiceXXX">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="callAMethodXXX">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW</prop>
    </props>
 </property>
```

Disclaimer: you might still have a problem with that approach, as you are calling an async method and you are not 100% sure that saveOrUpdate method in separate transaction is finished or not.